# Validating enums with AJV in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, jsonschema, ajv

Say I have an interface and schema like so:

```js
enum FooEnum {
  Bar = 'BAR',
}

interface Foo {
  enumValue: FooEnum.Bar
}

const schema = JSONSchemaType<Foo> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    enumValue: {
      const: Foo[FooEnum.Bar]
    }
  }
}
```

This will fail because typescript will complain that these are not the same type.

Two (related) questions:

1. how can I use AJV and Typescript with const values in the schema? Typescript complains even if the enum was replaced with string literals (see: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1984)
2. can AJV parse input enum values as the actual enum types that they are supposed to come out as? If so, how do I set that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question ended up being straightforward: I needed to give a type for the const value in the jsonschema.

```
constantValue: { type: 'string', const: 'FOO' }
```

The second seems like its not possible.

Comment: This should not be necessary. Ajv now uses a "strict mode" that is enabled by default that enforces non-standard constraints on your schemas. Unfortunately, these non-standard constraints are problematic in many cases such as this one. I highly suggest disabling strict mode.